# Rails routing to update a model without passing an :id

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing, simple-form

I have a pretty basic 'User' model, control & views for a Rails app.  I am trying to add a 'profile' section where the user can update their user info after logging in (and storing their user_id as a session variable).

I have scaffolded a basic 'profile' model, controller and views (_form, index and edit all using simple_form).  The model is empty and the views are pretty much a copy of the user views except I have moved the 'show' format to the profile index view.  In my controller I pretty much copied the user controller, deleted the new, create, show and destroy actions.

Here is what I have:

```
class ProfileController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @profile = User.find(session[:user_id])
  end

  def edit
    @profile = User.find(session[:user_id])
  end

  def update
    @profile = User.find(session[:user_id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.update_attributes(params[:profile])
        redirect_to @profile, notice: 'Profile was successfully updated.'
      else
        render action: "edit"
      end
    end
  end

 end
```

I tried both of these routes formats:

```
  match "profile" => "profile#index"  
  match "profile/edit" => "profile#edit"
  match "profile/update" => "profile#update"
```

and

```
  controller :profile do
    put 'profile/update' => :update
    get 'profile' => :index
    get 'profile/edit' => :edit
  end
```

When I load ~/profile/edit/ the form renders properly and my fields populate.  I am using simple_form and here is the start of my _form.html.erb file:

`<%= simple_form_for @profile, :url => url_for(:action => 'update', :controller => 'profile'), :html => { :id => "edit_profile", :class => 'form-horizontal' }, :method => 'put' do |f| %>`

but simple_form still passes `for="user_***"` to all the field inputs.

I updated `@profile.update_attributes(params[:profile])` to `@profile.update_attributes(params[:user])` thinking that was the issue.  When I click 'Update User' (still references the User model). The form reloads to ~/profile/update but nothing happens.

I am pretty sure I am missing an obvious routing / model issue here but I can't seem to figure this out on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume its not a routing / model issue here. Your edit profile page still references user because your `@profile` is a `User` and not a `Profile`.

First, if you want to follow Rails' convention, which I strongly recommend, use plural form for controller's class as `class ProfilesController < ApplicationController`.

Then, define routes for your profiles resource as `resources :profiles, :only => [:index, :edit, :update]`

Your profiles#edit as :

```
def edit
  @profile = User.find(session[:user_id]).profile #(i.e. if user has_one profile)
  # or @profile = Profile.find(params[:id) depending on what params are being passed here
end
```

Comment: I am new to Rails and the conventions so perhaps I am just looking at this the wrong way.  The User model is a basic set-up (name_first, name_last, email, phone, mobile, password hashes etc.).  I set it up using a scaffold with the intent that it was moved into an admin section where I would have various levels of creating, editing and updating happening.  I have the users associated to a Company model via a Role model.

Comment: The idea here is that the user logs in and they can update their 'profile' (name, phone numbers etc.) which in reality is just thier User object.  Then and admin User for that company can login, update their profile and also edit the account permissions (via Role) for all the Company Users.  My intent was to have the "~/profile/edit" structure rather than "~/users/1/edit".  I could do this and just validate the :id against session[:user_id] but the "~/profile" just looks cleaner.

Comment: All this being said should I just be keeping this all in my Users controller?  I have the 'profile' set up with the index as a show action but it really should just go direct to edit.  All I want is the user to edit & update.  The admin user can handle the create, and destroy (along with edit & update).

Comment: Yes `~/profile` looks much cleaner than `~/users/1/edit`, and it fits your requirements. Keeping this in profiles controller seems better even the profile is indeed a user object.

Comment: If you want the user to only edit & update, then `profiles#index` and `profiles#update` should suffice. You can render the form in index page and submit to `profiles#update` where `@profile = User.find(session[:user_id])` and update attributes using `params[:user]` should do the update. Try this out, and if it doesn't work then have `@profile.update_attributes!(params[:user])` in `profiles#update`. The `!` will show errors when doing an update.

Comment: you nailed it.  I added the ! and it was a password validation error I have on the User model.  I have validations in the Profiles model too but it seems to default back to the Users model.  I added a conditional validation like in this Railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/41-conditional-validations

I had to also manually edit some of my paths like edit_profile_path(@profile) to '/profile/edit/' because they too default to '/users/1/edit'.  Not sure how to fix that but not a big deal.  Thanks for the fix!